# How can I save a custom field of an attribute in Woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

### Old

I am trying to create a custom field in the product attributes in Woocommerce. This to be able to select if an attribute is highlighted or not. For example:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ge76B.png

What I want to do is that the field that I specify in backend as highlighted is displayed in a certain way in the frontend.

So far I have been able to add the field, but I have not managed to figure out how to save it. This is what I have:

```
add_action('woocommerce_after_product_attribute_settings','wcb_add_product_attribute_is_highlighted', 10, 2);
add_filter( 'woocommerce_admin_meta_boxes_prepare_attribute', 'wcb_admin_meta_boxes_prepare_attribute', 10, 3);

function get_attribute_highlighted($id, $i) {
    return get_post_meta( 1, "attribute_".$id."_highlighted_".$i, true);
}

function wcb_add_product_attribute_is_highlighted($attribute, $i=0) {
    $value = get_attribute_highlighted($attribute->get_id(), $i); ?>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="enable_variation show_if_canopytour show_if_variable_canopytour">
                <label><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" <?php checked( $value, true ); ?> name="attribute_highlighted[<?php echo esc_attr( $i ); ?>]" value="1" /> <?php esc_html_e( 'Highlight attribute', $this->wcb ); ?></label>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
<?php
}

function wcb_admin_meta_boxes_prepare_attribute($attribute, $data, $i=0) {
    // updated
    if(array_key_exists("attribute_highlighted", $data) && is_array($data["attribute_highlighted"])) {
        update_post_meta( 1, "attribute_".$attribute->get_id()."_highlighted_".$i, wc_string_to_bool($data["attribute_highlighted"][$i]) );
    }
}
```

I tried the `woocommerce_admin_meta_boxes_prepare_attribute` filter using the `offsetSet` and `offsetGet` methods of the `WC_Product_Attribute` class but I can not understand how it works. I could not make it save my custom value.

### Upgrade

I changed the `woocommerce_admin_meta_boxes_prepare_attribute` filter by the `wp_ajax_woocommerce_save_attributes` action and it seems to work. Now I have the problem that it is not updated after saving for the first time.

I explain the current problem: I have a checkbox that when clicked is activated, I save and when reloading the state it is maintained. If now I want to deactivate it, after saving the state it is not kept as disabled, it is put back as activated.

This is the updated code:

```
add_action('woocommerce_after_product_attribute_settings', 'wcb_add_product_attribute_is_highlighted', 10, 2);
add_action('wp_ajax_woocommerce_save_attributes', 'wcb_ajax_woocommerce_save_attributes', 10);

function get_attribute_highlighted($id, $i) {
    global $post;
    $id = sanitize_title($id);
    $id = strtolower($id);
    $val = get_post_meta( $post->ID, "attribute_".$id."_highlighted_".$i, true);
    return !empty($val) ? $val : false;
}

function wcb_add_product_attribute_is_highlighted($attribute, $i=0) {
    $value = get_attribute_highlighted($attribute->get_name(), $i); ?>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div class="enable_highlighted show_if_canopytour show_if_variable_canopytour">
                    <label><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" <?php checked( $value, true ); ?> name="attribute_highlighted[<?php echo esc_attr( $i ); ?>]" value="1" /> <?php esc_html_e( 'Highlight attribute', $this->wcb ); ?></label>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    <?php
}

function wcb_ajax_woocommerce_save_attributes() {
    check_ajax_referer( 'save-attributes', 'security' );
    parse_str( $_POST['data'], $data );
    $post_id = absint( $_POST['post_id'] );
    if(array_key_exists("attribute_highlighted", $data) && is_array($data["attribute_highlighted"])) {
        foreach($data["attribute_highlighted"] as $i => $val) {
            $attr_name = sanitize_title($data["attribute_names"][$i]);
            $attr_name = strtolower($attr_name);
            update_post_meta( $post_id, "attribute_".$attr_name."_highlighted_".$i, wc_string_to_bool($val) );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `offsetSet()` and `offsetGet()` are Old and not anymore used methods… You can see that in the source code: `ArrayAccess/Backwards compatibility.` I don't think that you can save and retrieve any custom data related to custom product attributes settings for a product post type. Is not possible to add, save and retrieve any other attribute argument key and value.

Comment: Hello @LoicTheAztec Thanks for comment, do you know any alternative? I really need this :(

Comment: I'm trying with `update_post_meta` and `get_post_meta` but it does not seem to work. I updated the code of my question.

Comment: I have tried everything possible, using the `global $post` which works on the first hook… It's just like `woocommerce_admin_meta_boxes_prepare_attribute` is not triggered. Nothing get saved even if you use for example hardcoded data with something like `update_post_meta( 37, '_highlighted_attribute', '1');` … **An action hook should be required** instead of a filter hook.

Comment: Thanks for trying, I will try to ask in github or slack. Maybe someone from the core team can help me. If I find a solution I'll publish it here.

Comment: The only possible way (much more complicated) should be to use some custom Ajax on field change event (jQuery + ajax).

Comment: I think I'm on the right track using the `wp_ajax_woocommerce_save_attributes` action however, even though I now save the first time, it's not updating me. I have updated the code to include my progress.

Comment: I don't see your code being updated yet…

Answer (score 5):

### Check [Ink's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65399443/8067370)

---

### Outdated

I have found the solution to my problem. I share the code in case someone is useful. Regards!

```
add_action('woocommerce_after_product_attribute_settings', 'wcb_add_product_attribute_is_highlighted', 10, 2);
add_action('wp_ajax_woocommerce_save_attributes', 'wcb_ajax_woocommerce_save_attributes', 10);

function get_attribute_highlighted($id, $i) {
    global $post;
    $id = sanitize_title($id);
    $id = strtolower($id);
    $val = get_post_meta( $post->ID, "attribute_".$id."_highlighted_".$i, true);
    return !empty($val) ? $val : false;
}

function wcb_add_product_attribute_is_highlighted($attribute, $i=0) {
    $value = get_attribute_highlighted($attribute->get_name(), $i); ?>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div class="enable_highlighted">
                    <label><input type="hidden" name="attribute_highlighted[<?php echo esc_attr( $i ); ?>]" value="0" /><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" <?php checked( $value, true ); ?> name="attribute_highlighted[<?php echo esc_attr( $i ); ?>]" value="1" /> <?php esc_html_e( 'Highlight attribute', $this->wcb ); ?></label>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    <?php
}

function wcb_ajax_woocommerce_save_attributes() {
    check_ajax_referer( 'save-attributes', 'security' );
    parse_str( $_POST['data'], $data );
    $post_id = absint( $_POST['post_id'] );
    if(array_key_exists("attribute_highlighted", $data) && is_array($data["attribute_highlighted"])) {
        foreach($data["attribute_highlighted"] as $i => $val) {
            $attr_name = sanitize_title($data["attribute_names"][$i]);
            $attr_name = strtolower($attr_name);
            update_post_meta( $post_id, "attribute_".$attr_name."_highlighted_".$i, wc_string_to_bool($val) );
        }
    }
}
```

In the end the only thing I had to add to my code was a hidden input with the same name as the checkbox but with a value of 0: `<input type="hidden" name="attribute_highlighted[<?php echo esc_attr( $i ); ?>]" value="0" />`

Here an image of the result (https://i.stack.imgur.com/VscT1.jpg). By clicking on save the value of the checkbox is maintained. The value is saved in a post_meta of the post that you are modifying. This is useful if you want to highlight a specific attribute in the front end.

I appreciate the help of @LoicTheAztec :)

Comment: For whom it doesn't work, just remove `<?php esc_html_e( 'Highlight attribute', $this->wcb ); ?>`

Answer (score 4):

As I struggled with the same issue I have tried using the code from Jesus Magallon. However, it did not work.

I found out that the priority of `wp_ajax_woocommerce_save_attributes` needed to be set to 0, otherwise the callback is not run for some reason.

Forthermore, if we only use `$post->ID` for `get_post_meta()` the correct results state of the checkbox will only be visible on page reload. To make sure the selected state is also visible direclty after ajax saving/reloading, we need to use `$post_id = isset( $_POST['post_id'] ) ? absint( $_POST['post_id'] ) : $post->ID;` instead.

Here the final version that should work perfectly for everyone:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_product_attribute_settings', 'wcb_add_product_attribute_is_highlighted', 10, 2);
add_action( 'wp_ajax_woocommerce_save_attributes', 'wcb_ajax_woocommerce_save_attributes', 0);

function get_attribute_highlighted( $attribute_name, $i ) {
    global $post;

    // ID for either from ajax or from post
    $post_id = isset( $_POST['post_id'] ) ? absint( $_POST['post_id'] ) : $post->ID ;
    $attribute_name = strtolower( sanitize_title( $attribute_name ) );
    $val = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'attribute_' . $attribute_name . '_highlighted_' . $i, true );

    return !empty( $val ) ? $val : false;
}

function wcb_add_product_attribute_is_highlighted( $attribute, $i=0 ) {
    $value = get_attribute_highlighted($attribute->get_name(), $i); ?>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div class="enable_highlighted">
                    <label>
                        <input type="hidden" name="attribute_highlighted[<?php echo esc_attr( $i ); ?>]" value="0" />
                        <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" <?php checked( $value, true ); ?> name="attribute_highlighted[<?php echo esc_attr( $i ); ?>]" value="1" />
                    <?php esc_html_e( 'Highlight attribute', 'textdomain' ); ?>
                </label>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    <?php
}

function wcb_ajax_woocommerce_save_attributes() {
    
    check_ajax_referer( 'save-attributes', 'security' );
                                                 
    parse_str( $_POST['data'], $data );
    $post_id = absint( $_POST['post_id'] );
    
    if( array_key_exists( 'attribute_highlighted', $data ) && is_array( $data['attribute_highlighted'] ) ) {
        foreach( $data['attribute_highlighted'] as $i => $val ) {
            $attr_name = sanitize_title( $data['attribute_names'][$i] );
            $attr_name = strtolower( $attr_name );
            update_post_meta( $post_id, 'attribute_' . $attr_name . '_highlighted_' . absint( $i ), wc_string_to_bool( $val ) );
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[@ink](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63476148/2148684) almost got it, but it's not working when you click on `Update` button of whole product directly. You always need to click on `Save attributes` button firstly and that's wrong, because when you try other checkboxes then you'll see it works also on `Update` click.

So I would completely remove that `add_action( 'wp_ajax_woocommerce_save_attributes', 'wcb_ajax_woocommerce_save_attributes', 0);` and `wcb_ajax_woocommerce_save_attributes` function and use this instead:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_admin_meta_boxes_prepare_attribute', function( $attribute, $data, $i ){
    global $post;
    if( is_object( $post ) && isset( $post->ID ) ){
        $post_id = $post->ID;
    }else{
        $post_id = absint( $_POST['post_id'] );
    }
    if( array_key_exists( 'attribute_highlighted', $data ) && is_array( $data['attribute_highlighted'] ) ){
        foreach( $data['attribute_highlighted'] as $i => $value ){
            $attr_name = sanitize_title( $data['attribute_names'][ $i ] );
            update_post_meta( $post_id, 'attribute_' . $attr_name . '_highlighted_' . absint( $i ), wc_string_to_bool( $value ) );
        }
    }
    return $attribute;
}, 10, 3 );
```

Answer (score 1):

perfect code but change the hook

```
add_action('wp_ajax_woocommerce_save_attributes', 'wcb_ajax_woocommerce_save_attributes', 10);
```

to

```
add_action('wp_ajax_woocommerce_save_attributes', 'wcb_ajax_woocommerce_save_attributes', 0);
```

Comment: While this may technically answer the question, it would be much better if you were to [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52878984/edit) it and explain what this code change does, and why it will fix the problem.

Comment: its about the priority of the execute this action :)

Answer (score 1):

[@Jesús Magallón's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52316433/8990164)

Answer need little modifications.
Remove the function `get_attribute_highlighted()` and replace this line

```
   $value = get_attribute_highlighted($attribute->get_name(), $i);
```

TO

```
    global $post;
    $post_id = isset($_POST['post_id']) ? absint($_POST['post_id']) : $post->ID ;
    $value = get_post_meta($post_id , "attribute_description".$i, true);
```

It will show ajax saved value instance of empty;

And Change hooks

```
add_action('wp_ajax_woocommerce_save_attributes', 'wcb_ajax_woocommerce_save_attributes', 10);
```

TO

```
add_action('wp_ajax_woocommerce_save_attributes', 'wcb_ajax_woocommerce_save_attributes', 0);
```