# How to add a description field on each product attribute for each product?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, attributes, product, product-variations

I am trying to add a description box to add a description for each attribute for each product. I have tried this solution [How can I save a custom field of an attribute in Woocommerce?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52283313/how-can-i-save-a-custom-field-of-an-attribute-in-woocommerce-) It added the code but, the ajax save is not working.

So, I will need the way to add description box + ajax saving and the way to display this description.

[image]

Comment: An answer given below, now deleted, said that [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63476148) would be helpful.